# AS3 Facebook APi - No dialogue for unathorised app

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I've got a Facebook app integrated into a Flash web/mobile app that works really well if the user is logged in, and authorised to use the app with the following code:

```
  private function facebookInit():void   
    {
            Facebook.init(APP_ID, facebookInitHandler,{
                appId: APP_ID,
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfmbl: true,
                channelUrl:     'http://mysite.net/channel.html',
                oauth: true,
                perms: 'publish_stream,email'
            });

    }

    private function facebookInitHandler(response:Object, fail:Object):void
    {

            if (response.accessToken)
            {
                var userAccessToken:String = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.encode(response.accessToken);
                facebookLoggedInWithToken = true;
                loadProfileData();
            } else {
                facebookLoggedInWithToken = false;
            }

    }

    private function loadProfileData():void
    {
        var request:String = "/me";
        var requestType:String = "GET";
        var params:Object = null;
        Facebook.api(request, loadProfileDataHandler, params, requestType);
    }
```

My problem is for users who are not logged in or have not authorised the app. I get a response with a null access code, and no dialogue popping up asking them to log in etc.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What's that Facebook class? Where does it come from? There are more than 10 libraries that provide the api, which one do you use? Provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used a try.. catch and caught when response was getting returned without an accesscode. Did a seperate login after that.